# Why does my 2GR FE engine sound horrible when put in Drive?

Tags: engine, toyota, noise, camry

I have a video showing the sound pretty well but the car sounds fine at idle in Neutral and Park but when put into drive it drops into this deep rumble.

[Take a listen:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PuaZjfjQoDyXoURtKzgxsIQ649My9aSX/view?usp=sharing)

It's a 2007 Toyota Camry LE V6 3.5L with 161k miles on it.